# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>props.navigation.openDrawer()}  style={[styles.menuicon]}>
   <Icon name='menu' type='entypo' size={30} color={color.white}>
   </Icon>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have `openDrawer()` function available inside the props.navigation

Comment: You should share the enough file content. Seems like you are trying to use Drawer Navigation. If you did not use `Drawer.Screen` for rendering the component, `props.navigation` might not have `openDrawer` function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`props.navigation` is often undefined on initial render until react-navigation provides it. Try guarding the function: `() => props.navigation?.openDrawer()`