# TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes (React Native Expo) (UPDATE: fixed it already)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-hermes, expo-go

I am building an app with **React Native Exp**o that includes a form that uses *datetimepicker*.

The error always occurs after I submit a third form. The first two submissions always work just fine so my max number of entries is two.

However, after updating my dependencies, the error now occurs on the second submission. So now I can only have a max of one entry on my app.

The error log on my *expo app* looks like this:

```
Uncaught Error
undefined is not a function

// Expo SDK 41-44
return NativeModules.ExpoRandom.getRandomBase64String(byteLength)
} else if (global.ExpoModules) {

// Expo SDK 45+
return global.ExpoModules.ExpoRandom.getRandomBase64String(byteLength);
} else {
```

Here's my code for the `ExpenseForm.tsx`:

```
import DateTimePicker, { DateTimePickerEvent } from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, SafeAreaView, Pressable, View } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import { useStore } from '../stores';

const ExpenseForm = () => {
  const { expenseStore } = useStore();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    amount: 0,
    name: '',
    description: '',
    category: '',
    date: new Date().toDateString(),
  });
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [showPicker, setShowPicker] = useState(false);

  const toggleDatepicker = () => {
    setShowPicker(!showPicker);
  };

  const onChange = ({ type }: DateTimePickerEvent, chosenDate: Date | undefined) => {
    if (type === 'set') {
      const currentDate = chosenDate || new Date();
      setSelectedDate(currentDate);
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        date: currentDate.toDateString(),
      });

      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        toggleDatepicker();
      }
    } else {
      toggleDatepicker();
    }
  };

  const confirmIOSDate = () => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, date: selectedDate.toDateString() });
    toggleDatepicker();
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (formData.amount === 0) {
      alert('Amount is required');
      setFormData({
        amount: 0,
        name: '',
        description: '',
        category: '',
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      });
      return;
    }

    if (formData.name.trim().length === 0) {
      alert('Name is required');
      setFormData({
        amount: 0,
        name: '',
        description: '',
        category: '',
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      });
      return;
    }

    expenseStore.addExpense(
      formData.amount,
      formData.name,
      formData.description,
      formData.category,
      formData.date
    );

    alert(
      `Expense successfully added! Amount: ${formData.amount}. Name: ${formData.name}. Description: ${formData.description}. Category: ${formData.category}. Date: ${formData.date}`
    );

    setFormData({
      amount: 0,
      name: '',
      description: '',
      category: '',
      date: new Date().toDateString(),
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Amount"
        value={formData.amount.toString()}
        onChangeText={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, amount: parseInt(e, 10) || 0 })}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Name"
        value={formData.name}
        onChangeText={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, name: e })}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.input, { height: 180 }]}
        placeholder="Description"
        multiline
        value={formData.description}
        onChangeText={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, description: e })}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Category"
        value={formData.category}
        onChangeText={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, category: e })}
      />
      {showPicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          mode="date"
          display="spinner"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={onChange}
          style={styles.datePicker}
        />
      )}

      {showPicker && Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.button, styles.pickerButton, { backgroundColor: '#11182711' }]}
            onPress={toggleDatepicker}>
            <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: '#075985' }]}>Cancel</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.pickerButton]} onPress={confirmIOSDate}>
            <Text style={[styles.buttonText]}>Confirm</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}

      {!showPicker && (
        <Pressable onPress={toggleDatepicker}>
          <TextInput
            style={[styles.input, { color: formData.date === '' ? 'gray' : 'black' }]}
            editable={false}
            onPressIn={toggleDatepicker}
            placeholder="Date"
            value={formData.date}
          />
        </Pressable>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onSubmit}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#fff',
  },
  datePicker: {
    height: 120,
    marginTop: -10,
  },
  pickerButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
});

export default observer(ExpenseForm);
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-expense-tracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "mobx": "^6.9.0",
    "mobx-keystone": "^1.6.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.1",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "universe/native"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried submitting a form and the error occurs. Weirdly, the first submission always works just fine.

UPDATE: the problem is in my ExpenseStore.ts file. already fixed the error! i followed this method github.com/expo/expo/issues/17270

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm not that familiar with React but I think this answer will help you solve the issue; https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781617/8658598 . Could you try that solution and update your question?

Comment: already fixed the error! i followed this method https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17270